# Error that causes intellisense failure in VS 2010 in web controls/pages

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a web application project that I recently converted from VS2008 to VS2010, it does not use .Net 4.0 (3.5 instead) but whenever I open the markup in a page or control it displays the following error and subsequently disables intellisense:

http://www.kompeller.co.uk/images/vs2010_error.png

Line 12 in my web.config looks like this:

```
 <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
      <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

The app is configured to run from IIS on my machine, and it has no parent websites so it is not inheriting from another web.config.

I've looked everywhere for a solution, it's driving me up the wall!

Thanks

Comment: From my reading that line that you've quoted would be the duplicate line. Is there a system.web.extensions defined before that somewhere?

Comment: No, there is no duplicate above that, just 2 other sections completely unrelated.  It seems to be affecting all of my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally tracked it down, based on James suggestion that the duplicate might not be at that line, this was the offending configuration:

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I removed this and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be exactly on line 12. The error very clearly states that `System.Web.Extensions` is defined twice in the web.config though. Just search for all instances of `System.Web.Extensions` and remove the duplicate.

Check the `assemblies` section and make sure there are no duplicates:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Drawing.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />      
      <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Check the `pages/controls` section and make sure there are no duplicates:

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 
        ...
```

Check the `httpHandlers` section:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    ...
```

Comment: I've done that and there are no duplicates within those sections.  The interesting thing is that this only started happening after I converted to 2010, and I've compared the versions in source control and there were no significant changes.

Comment: Your answer prompted me to find other occurrances, see my answer below, thanks!

Comment: I told you to search for any instances of System.Web.Extensions, and replace the duplicate...

Comment: Not sure I follow, replace the duplicate with what?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "remove the duplicate."